# how to store address from google map to a variable in php or html or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, google-maps

I'm creating a form based website where I need the user to click on the google map for his location. when the user clicks submit, the address from google map should be stored into a variable. is it possible?

I need it because in the form, there is also an option for photo uploading, and I'm saving the photo to my server file system.

But I have other data(e.g. name, age etc.) which are saved on MySQL database. so to link the image & the MySQL data,

I need to add that address variable from google map to the image name when it uploads to the file system.

So is this possible? I just don't have any idea how should I store the address from google map to a variable for image name change.

```
<style type="text/css">
  div#map {
    position: relative;
  }

  div#crosshair {
    position: absolute;
    top: 192px; 
    height: 19px;
     width: 19px;
     left: 50%;
    margin-left: -8px;
    display: block;
     background: url(crosshair.gif);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?          sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
  var geocoder;
  var centerChangedLast;
  var reverseGeocodedLast;
  var currentReverseGeocodeResponse;

  function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(32.5468,-23.2031);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 2,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),  myOptions);
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();


    setupEvents();
    centerChanged();
  }

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
  placeMarker(event.latLng);
  });

function placeMarker(location) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'Latitude: ' + location.lat() +
    '<br>Longitude: ' + location.lng()
  });
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
}

  function setupEvents() {
    reverseGeocodedLast = new Date();
centerChangedLast = new Date();

setInterval(function() {
  if((new Date()).getSeconds() - centerChangedLast.getSeconds() > 1) {
    if(reverseGeocodedLast.getTime() < centerChangedLast.getTime())
      reverseGeocode();
  }
}, 1000);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
  document.getElementById("zoom_level").innerHTML = map.getZoom();
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', centerChanged);

google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('crosshair'),'dblclick', function() {
   map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
});

  }

  function getCenterLatLngText() {
     return '(' + map.getCenter().lat() +', '+ map.getCenter().lng()  +')';
  }

  function centerChanged() {
    centerChangedLast = new Date();
    var latlng = getCenterLatLngText();
    document.getElementById('latlng').innerHTML = latlng;
    document.getElementById('formatedAddress').innerHTML = '';
    currentReverseGeocodeResponse = null;
  }

  function reverseGeocode() {
    reverseGeocodedLast = new Date();
    geocoder.geocode({latLng:map.getCenter()},reverseGeocodeResult);
  }

   function reverseGeocodeResult(results, status) {
    currentReverseGeocodeResponse = results;
    if(status == 'OK') {
      if(results.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById('formatedAddress').innerHTML = 'None';
      } else {
        document.getElementById('formatedAddress').innerHTML =     results[0].formatted_address;
      }
    } else {
      document.getElementById('formatedAddress').innerHTML = 'Error';
    }
  }


      function geocode() {
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    geocoder.geocode({
      'address': address,
      'partialmatch': true}, geocodeResult);
  }

  function geocodeResult(results, status) {
    if (status == 'OK' && results.length > 0) {
      map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " +     status);
     }
  }

  function addMarkerAtCenter() {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map
});

var text = 'Lat/Lng: ' + getCenterLatLngText();
if(currentReverseGeocodeResponse) {
  var addr = '';
  if(currentReverseGeocodeResponse.size == 0) {
    addr = 'None';
  } else {
    addr = currentReverseGeocodeResponse[0].formatted_address;
  }
  text = text + '<br>' + 'address: <br>' + addr;
}

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: text });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
  }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: provide some source code. You can't ask others here to solve your problem for you. Show what you have tried and accomplished and where you failed so others can guide you and point your mistakes.

Comment: As @Barracuda said, we need more information.
For now, all I can say to help is that you should be storing latitude/altitude, it would be much easier and accurate than an address

Comment: All I have is the google Api I used. I'm giving you the api code.

Comment: look like you already have a click event for the google map..you can add a variable there to retrieve the lat long as pablito suggests:
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (e) {
    var latLng = e.latLng;
});
you can then use the Google Maps API to reverse geocode those coordinates.